# Rails best in place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I followed Ryan Bates' [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?autoplay=true) on the best in place gem but cannot get it to work properly. The default value I set before_create in the user.rb model is showing up on the page but I cannot click on it to edit; it's just showing as a static element. Although, Firebug is showing that the best_in_place javascript is being loaded in the view `<head>`.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
```

users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

user.rb

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :goal
...
before_create :default_values
...
  private

    def default_values
      self.goal ||= "Write Current Goal Here"
    end
```

users_controller.rb

```
respond_to :html, :json
...
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html {
          flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
          sign_in @user
          redirect_to @user
        }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      else
        format.html { render 'edit' }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      end
    end
  end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
...
<%= best_in_place @user, :goal %>
```

Comment: Any errors on the browser's console?  Try to click it even if you don't see the animation

Comment: Tried clicking to no avail. There is an error actually. Console says:
`$(".best_in_place").best_in_place is not a function`

Comment: just place with the order of required files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layouts/application.html.erb .. instead of `javascript_include_tag(:all)` do

```
javascript_include_tag(:application)
```

Also, make sure that `users.js.coffee` lives in `app/assets/javascript`

**Edit**

Ensure that you have the gem specified in the Gemfile and bundle installed

```
gem "best_in_place"
```

Try this, like Said Kaldybaev suggested

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require_tree .
//= require best_in_place
```

then instead of coffee do this at the top of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
})
```

If that doesn't work, remove `//= require best_in_place` and `//= require jquery.purr` then run

```
rails g best_in_place:setup
```

Comment: It's currently set to: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`
The `users.js.coffee` file is in `app/assets/javascript`

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the coffee DOM call with script
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`
  `$('.best_in_place').best_in_place();`
`})`

This code didn't work:
`$(document).ready(function() {`
  `$('.best_in_place').best_in_place();`
`})`

Answer (score 1):

me also had the same problem, solved by moving the **require best_in_place** to the end of require list

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require_tree .
//= require best_in_place
```

Comment: Tried moving best_in_place to the bottom but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: did you run rails g best_in_place:setup ?

Comment: No. I assumed I didn't have to since I manually edited the javascript files as Ryan suggested. Should I try to run it with the current files edited or undo the changes I made first then run the setup cmd?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Activating Best In Place */
jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

To

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```